# building a website with free registration but has to pay for certain facilities everytime user uses them?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-modules

let me be clear first its not like i am trying to build a members area. There are hundreds of posts on that topic.

this is what i want to achieve.

1)a very basic website where registration is completely free and no credit card details or anything is required at that time.

2)a section in the website where a person can upload files (music created by the user or his band in my case).

3)everytime he wants to upload the music (a singe or an album), he pays using credit card or paypal and then has to pay every month until he mails us that he doesnt want t continue.

4) for an example head over to [www.tunecore.com](http://www.tunecore.com) but with drupal obviously.

5)I am hoping to use drupal 7 as it is newer and will be supported for a longer period of time and as i have read many features come out of the box but drupal 6 is also acceptable if i can achieve the goals .

P.S. i tried searching for this(9 days * 11 hrs to be exact) but couldnt find anything thats why i am posting here.

the reason we are choosing drupal is that its completely free , highly customisable , very secure and best of all easy to manage so it will decrease our setup cost which as a startup we always look for.

i am looking for suggestions,modules, custom builds, tutorials, blog posts or basically anything to help me and my startup to achieve what we aim.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Ubercart 3.0 is available for drupal7, it's not entirely what you want, but perhaps you can check it out and adapt when to require a paypal payment.

Comment: i tried it before but i wasnt able to modify as i wanted .... but ill give it a second try........ thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going with Drupal 7, you should probably try [Drupal Commerce](http://www.drupalcommerce.org/).

As for what you're trying to achieve, you could probably look into [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) as well as user roles.